# Reading the files contents to the allocated string

Tags: c, file, malloc

I am trying to read the contents of a file and copy those contents into a string which has dynamic memory. However my program keeps allocating only 8 bytes to *x. Ultimately I'm trying to create a general function that can read contents from a file and then return the contents as a char*. Any help is appreciated.

```
char* readFile(unsigned long size, char *fileName) {

FILE *file = fopen(fileName, "r");
int c;
if(file != NULL)
{
    while(c != EOF){ //calculate size of file
        c = fgetc(file); //store character
        size++;
    }
    char *x = (char *)malloc((size) * (sizeof(char))); // Size of x = 8 and I'm not sure why
    rewind(file);
    printf("\n");

    int i = 0;
    while(size - 1 > i){ //Reading the files contents to the allocated string
        c = fgetc(file); //store character
        if(c == EOF){
            break;
        }
        x[i] = c;
        i++;
    }

    fclose(file);
    printf("Done Reading");
 }
else
{
 printf("\nError: Unable to open the file for Reading.\n");
}
rewind(file);
return 0;
```

}

I get a segmentation fault when I run

```
char* str = readFile(size, originalFile);
```

Comment: `fgetc()` returns `int`, not `char`.  Cramming the `int` value returned from `fgetc()` into a `char` means you will not be able to reliably detect `EOF` - **because `EOF` is not a `char` value**.

Comment: How exactly are you measuring the memory you have allocated?

Comment: `while(c != EOF)` in the first iteration `c` is used uninitialized.

Comment: `readFile` returns `char *` but the only `return` statement in it is: `return 0;` (i.e.) it returns `NULL` What do you _want_ to return?

Comment: Why are you passing `size` as a parameter? It is _added_ to in the function but you have to rely on caller to pass 0. What you probably want is: `size_t readFile(const char *fileName)` as a signature and want to do: `return size;` You'll need a local variable: `size_t size = 0;` in the function. Actually, you probably want `off_t` instead of `size_t` to account for very large files.

Comment: *Size of x = 8 and I'm not sure why?* `x` is a pointer, it's the usual size of a pointer, you already have the size of the allocated memory given to you by `size`.

Answer (score 2):

I would use [stat](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lstat.2.html) to first get the size of your file

> stat() retrieves information about the file pointed
> to by pathname;

And then I made some tiny modifications to your function to make it work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

char* readFile(char *fileName) {
    FILE *file;
    struct stat st;

    if (!(file = fopen(fileName, "r")))
        return NULL;
    stat(fileName, &st);
    unsigned long size = st.st_size;
    char *x;
    if (!(x = (char *)malloc((size + 1) * (sizeof(char))))) // Size of x = 8 and I'm not sure why
        return NULL;
    unsigned long i = 0;
    while (i < size) //Reading the files contents to the allocated string
        x[i++] = getc(file);
    x[i] = '\0';
    fclose(file);
    printf("Done Reading\n");
    return x;
}

int main(void) {
    char *fileName = "a.txt";

    char *res = readFile(fileName);
    printf("%s\n", res);
    return 0;
}
```

Don't forget that in C [strings are NULL terminated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string), you need to malloc size+1 to add the final '\0'.

Comment: I would use `if (!(x = malloc(size + 1))) `, the current expression is needlessly complicated, `char` is universally 1 byte, `i` should also be `unsigned long`, avoiding comparing unsigned with signed types.

Comment: not in C# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/char but I agree

Comment: Yes, C# trickery to overcome the Windows Unicode mess.

Answer (score 0):

This is (IMHO) an easier way to find the size of the file:

```
char *readFile(const char *fileName)
{

    unsigned long size = 0;
    char *x;
    FILE *file = fopen(fileName, "r");
    int c;
    if (file != NULL)
    {
        fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);            /* SET the position at EOF */
        size = ftell(file);                  /* Record the position at EOF to return size of file */
        rewind(file);                        /* SET position back to Origin */
        printf("size detected %ld\n", size); // reads correct size

        x = (char *)malloc((size) * (sizeof(char)));
        rewind(file);
        printf("\n");

        int i = 0;
        while (size - 1 > i)
        {                    //Reading the files contents to the allocated string
            c = fgetc(file); //store character
            if (c == EOF)
            {
                break;
            }
            x[i] = c;
            i++;
        }

        fclose(file);
        printf("Done Reading\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nError: Unable to open the file for Reading.\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    rewind(file);

    return x; // * you need to return x not zero
}
```

Successfully reads the content of the file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *data;
    data = readFile("records.txt");
    printf("%s\n", data);
    return 0;
}
```